# WKWebView rendering abnormal

Tags: ios, webview, webkit, wkwebview

I'm using  WKWebview  for pre loading some pages, which means that I load url first , and added to view hierarcy later at some point.  The page got rendering error as attatched oftenly but not everytime. I had also wrote a playgroud demo , the error can be re-produced by toggle attach/deattch webview. 
Can any one give me a hand on this? 
[the page rendered as following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C7Wt.jpg)

Comment: Can you please show us the code as how you have written it?

Comment: fixed by give the webview a bounds instead of cgzero

Comment: It would be useful for others if you share your code.